# How to sort a small amount(around 100~200) of (~16~bit) numbers on GPU CUDA very very fast?

Tags: sorting, cuda, gpgpu, gpu, radix-sort

Hi is part of my project. The key is that I have to sort a array of numbers (say 100~200 16 bits numbers, numbers and bits are fixed before hand). I want to sort this within one block using shared memory of GPU, as part of the requirement the data could not go off-chip in middle.

I have read some radix sorting, bitonic sorting algorithm on GPU. But it looks like they are designed for large amount of numbers. I want to sort this 100~200 numbers very very quickly

I appreciate any idea/help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CUB](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub) has routines to do sorting operations within a single block, including [examples](https://github.com/NVlabs/cub/blob/1.1.1/examples/block/example_block_radix_sort.cu).  CUB also has routines that can run at the device level if you desire, to leverage all of the compute resources for larger problem sizes.

For 100+ numbers to be sorted, you're not likely to be able to write your own code that runs any faster.

If you have a very small group (say < 32) numbers to sort at the block level, you may simply want to write your own code.  In that case, the [warp vote and shuffle](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) instructions are likely to be useful.

Comment: Do they utilize capability 3.0 shuffle instructions in cub?

Comment: Yes.  cub is an open-source header library, so you can inspect it yourself.  The shfl instructions in it mostly appear in inline assembly regions.

Comment: I am looking at the example:

int thread_keys[16];
     BlockLoad(temp_storage.load).Load(d_in + block_offset, thread_keys);
     __syncthreads();

Here, "thread_keys" will be allocated in global memory right? Could I only have 1 key per thread and have it in register, onchip only?  It looks like Blockload.load is taking a pointer as parameter. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The comments is not a sensible place to try and cover this. Please post your question about how to use CUB as a new SO question.